# Data.frame Merge and Selection of values which are common in 2 Data.frames

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have 3 data.frames

```
> head(ON1)
  Entrez.ID Nearest.Refseq Gene.Name Tag.Count
1     11302      NM_007377      Aatk    137.48
2     11303      NM_013454     Abca1    118.09
3     11305      NM_007379     Abca2     93.56
4     11306      NM_009592     Abcb7     92.42
5     11308      NM_007380      Abi1    410.73
6     11356      NM_009598      Abl5    149.46

 > head(ON2)
  Entrez.ID Nearest.Refseq Gene.Name Tag.Count
1     11303      NM_013454     Abca1     86.02
2     11305      NM_007379     Abca2    103.45
3     11306      NM_009592     Abcb7     95.32
4     11308      NM_007380      Abi1    313.85
5     11350      NM_009594      Abl1    116.24
6     11352      NM_009595      Abl2    155.76

> head(ON3)
  Entrez.ID Nearest.Refseq Gene.Name Tag.Count
1     11303      NM_013454     Abca1     69.49
2     11305      NM_007379     Abca2     82.02
3     11306      NM_009592     Abcb7     83.16
4     11308      NM_007380      Abi1    306.44
5     11350      NM_009594      Abl1    150.37
6     11355      NM_009599      Abl4    154.93
```

Some rows are unique to only 1 data.frame (e.g. `row1` of `ON1`), some are common in 2 data.frames (e.g. `row5` of `ON2` and `ON3`, this row doesn't exist in `ON1`) and some are common in all data.frames (e.g. `row2` of `ON1` which is `row1` in `ON2` and `ON3`). **The only difference is the values in last column `Tag.Count`**

I want to merge all 3 data.frames in such a way that I obtain only those rows in my final data.frame which are common among at-least 2 data.frames and the value of `Tag.Count` which is higher among them will be assigned to that row.

```
> head(F)
  Entrez.ID Nearest.Refseq Gene.Name Tag.Count
1     11303      NM_013454     Abca1     118.09
2     11305      NM_007379     Abca2     103.45
3     11306      NM_009592     Abcb7     95.32
4     11308      NM_007380      Abi1    410.73
5     11350      NM_009594      Abl1    150.37
```

Here you see that rows with `Entrez.ID` = `11302` is removed as it only appeard once among all the data.frames and those rows which were common in at least 2 data.frames are appearing here but the `Tag.Count` score which was maximum among all the data.frames is assigned to that row.

**UPDATE**

How to take average of rows. After merging above three datasets, instead of just keeping one row which has maximum `Tag.count` value, I want to sum the `Tag.count` value and divide by total number of rows having the same `Entrez.ID`. In fact the values in the first 3 columns are the same, difference only arises in last column. 
Example:

```
> head(d)
      Entrez.ID Nearest.Refseq Gene.Name Tag.Count
1         11302      NM_007377      Aatk    137.48
2         11303      NM_013454     Abca1    118.09
7886      11303      NM_013454     Abca1     86.02
15407     11303      NM_013454     Abca1     69.49
3         11305      NM_007379     Abca2     93.56
7887      11305      NM_007379     Abca2    103.45
```

So, in this case as 3 rows have `Entrez.ID` = 11303, the `Tag.count` values will be summed up (118.09 + 86.02 + 69.49) and divided by 3 and final output will contain only 1 row having `Entrez.ID` 11303 and `Tag.Count value` = Sum/no.of Rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way with combining the three data frames. After combining all three, we find the values that appear more than once. With that index we can aggregate the data frame with the function `max`:

```
d <- do.call(rbind, list(ON1, ON2, ON3))
d1 <- do.call(paste, d[1:3])
tbl <- table(d1) > 1L
indx <- d1 %in% names(tbl[tbl])
aggregate(Tag.Count ~., d[indx,], FUN=max)
#   Entrez.ID Nearest.Refseq Gene.Name Tag.Count
# 1     11303      NM_013454     Abca1    118.09
# 2     11305      NM_007379     Abca2    103.45
# 3     11306      NM_009592     Abcb7     95.32
# 4     11308      NM_007380      Abi1    410.73
# 5     11350      NM_009594      Abl1    150.37
```

Comment: Thanks @Pierre It did the job

Comment: @Pierre I have an update to the question, can you help me solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Newbie, regarding your update, have you tried replacing `FUN=max` by `FUN=mean`?...

Comment: @Newbie use `aggregate(Tag.Count~., d, mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in dplyr by binding the three together, filtering out groups with one element, and then picking the top `Tag.Count` in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

F <- bind_rows(ON1, ON2, ON3) %>%
  group_by(Entrez.ID) %>%    # elements are in same group if same Entrez.ID
  filter(n() > 1) %>%        # filter out groups with 1 element
  top_n(1, Tag.Count)        # pick highest Tag.Count from each
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidRobinson

Comment: @David I have an update to the question, can you help me solving this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the update:

#### preliminaries

```
tab <- structure(
  list(
    Entrez.ID = c(11302L, 11303L, 11303L, 11303L, 11305L, 11305L),
    Nearest.Refseq = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L),
                               .Label = c("NM_007377", "NM_007379", "NM_013454"),
                               class = "factor"),
    Gene.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
                          .Label = c("Aatk", "Abca1", "Abca2"),
                          class = "factor"),
    Tag.Count = c(137.48, 118.09, 86.02, 69.49, 93.56, 103.45)
  ),
  .Names = c("Entrez.ID", "Nearest.Refseq", "Gene.Name", "Tag.Count"),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c("1", "2", "7886", "15407", "3", "7887")
)
print(tab)
#       Entrez.ID Nearest.Refseq Gene.Name Tag.Count
# 1         11302      NM_007377      Aatk    137.48
# 2         11303      NM_013454     Abca1    118.09
# 7886      11303      NM_013454     Abca1     86.02
# 15407     11303      NM_013454     Abca1     69.49
# 3         11305      NM_007379     Abca2     93.56
# 7887      11305      NM_007379     Abca2    103.45
```

#### `dplyr` way

```
library(dplyr)
(res <- tab %>% group_by(Entrez.ID) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% summarise(Means = mean(Tag.Count)))
```

Result:

```
  Entrez.ID   Means
      (int)   (dbl)
1     11302 137.480
2     11303  91.200
3     11305  98.505
```

#### Pure `data.table` way, after David Arenburg comment

```
library(data.table)
(res <- setDT(tab)[, if(.N > 1) { .(Means = mean(Tag.Count)) }, by = Entrez.ID])
```

Result same as above.

#### Leave `Nearest.Refseq` and `Gene.Name` columns

Two possible `dplyr` solutions, pick one:

Assuming `Nearest.Refseq` and `Gene.Name` are unique for every `Gene.Name`:

```
res <- tab %>% group_by(Entrez.ID) %>% summarise(Nearest.Refseq = Nearest.Refseq[1], Gene.Name = Gene.Name[1], Means = mean(Tag.Count))
```

If not you need to do something with them (replace `someFunction()`!):

```
res <- tab %>% group_by(Entrez.ID) %>% summarise(Nearest.Refseq = someFunction(Nearest.Refseq), Gene.Name = someFunction(Gene.Name), Means = mean(Tag.Count))
```

Edit: Mixed `data.table`/`dplyr` approach removed.

Comment: This is not the "*data.table way*". `data.table` way would be just `setDT(tab)[, .(Means = mean(Tag.Count)), by = Entrez.ID]`. I've never seen a single pipe in any `data.table` tutorial.

Comment: @M.D Thanks for answering. I also want the middle 2 columns in the final output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you are right, lets then call it "mixed approach", where crucial parts are done with `data.table`, but pipe from `dplyr` makes it a bit more readable. I will add your pure `data.table` way to the answer.

Comment: @Newbie There is a whole thread dedicated to that topic. Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame) ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I am not sure if the user referencing works in answers, but I have added yours comment to it.

Comment: @M.D I have seen the link you provided but I am unable to understand how I can add all of the columns in the final output. I can do it other way by merging but I think there will be a simpler way than this.

Comment: @M.D One thing I noticed now is that one condition which I posted in my original question is not fulfilled by your answer, that was, only those rows should be retained that appears in at least 2 data sets (as the input data.frame to your code is a merge of 3 data.frames). So, in simple words in this case as the first row having `Entrez.ID = 11302`should be discarded as it appeared only in one dataset.

Comment: @M.D I got it, I just had to add the filter: `filter(n() > 1)`

Comment: @user3253470, yeah, `filter(n() > 1)` in `dplyr` and `if(.N > 1)` for `data.table`, I've edited both approaches.